# Shell Context Menus in C, C++

Tags: c++, c, shell

Is it possible to add shell context menus to all `.txt` files via a C or C++ (either) program?

I have been creating these menus by directly accessing the registry. Also, I found `C#`

specific code and certain other implementation specific `c, C++` versions.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest methods are in the ["Shell Lightweight API"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is API that allows you to access the registry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that your application must run as administator, otherwise the change will be "[virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx)".

You can see some code on how to elevate the permissions of an application [in this help file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/9/B/D9BEB875-BC1D-4338-A655-251F4F353B2E/Top10Wave.exe). Topic Fundamentals>Secure Applications>Designing UAC Applications for Windows Vista>Step 3: Redisign for UAC Compatibility, Step 4: Redesign Your UI for UAC Compatibility.

Comment: Your application doesn't have to run as administrator, if you use the appropriate registry keys (`HKCU` - Current User). Administrator rights are only needed to make systemwide changes.

Comment: That's not a real key. It's a merged view of HKLM\Software\Classes and HKCU\Software\Classes.